# Android: Pass data to a child activity, Detect who is the parent

Tags: android, android-activity

I wounder if there is some possible to know from which parent Iam coming from in the child so I can do different stuff depending on who the parent is of the activity..

This is how Iam going over to the child. But I don't know how to handle this in the child to check who is the parent.

```
    public void chooseLocation(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClass(InsertAd.this, Location.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, REQ_CODE_SELECT_LOCATION);
}
```

The above code is used on one of the parents,, is there somehow I can use "EQ_CODE_SELECT_LOCATION"?

Also I wounder how is possible to send data to a child activity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put in Extra of your intent to pass extra data. eg:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("CallerClass", "com.example.callingActivity");
...
```

and later in your Location.class, you can retrieve those extra via getIntent()

```
string caller = getIntent.getExtras().getString("CallerClass");
```

Comment: do I need to use onActivityResult=

Comment: If you need to return result.